# How can i added my on barcode and decode it using zxing?

Tags: android, zxing

I'm having a particular barcode format. I need to decode it using zxing.

How can i use zxing for decoding it?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using zxing as a library in your application or do you want it to be called by an intent?

Comment: I'm using zxing as the library in my app.

Comment: Well, would you mind revealing what barcode format you have in mind?

Comment: The barcode format i'm having is that not specified in the zxing library. How i can add that to zxing and deocded it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would implement the `Reader` interface with whatever logic you need to read the barcode. See the other implementations for clues about how it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ZXing in 2 ways

1. Intent method
2. Integrate ZXing into your code without using intent method. This method should be used only if you have sound knowledge of ZXing library.

The developers of ZXing encourage us to use the 1st method.

But since you ave mentioned that you are using ZXing as library in your app,
follow the steps in this link http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

All the steps are explained in a detailed manner.

**NOTE:** Do not use this method unless it is absolutely necessary.
The developers of ZXing encourage using core/ as a library, since it's a library. You shouldn't use android/ as a library, simply because it isn't. They really discourage copying and pasting android/.

Comment: We don't discourage using zxing as a library. We encourage using core/ as a library, since it's a library. You shouldn't use android/ as a library, simply because it isn't. What we really discourage is copying and pasting android/. So yes you are correct, #1 is the preferred option, just wanted to clarify.